# How JS forEach works with ternary and if operators?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to understand about 2 hours what I am doing wrong in third and fourth line of code. The console thows out `SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` or `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. The first and the second line works as expected.

```
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => console.log(typeof el !== 'string'))

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => if (typeof el !== 'string') { console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`)} )

let checkArr = ((arr) => { arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null; )})

checkArr(arr);
```

Comment: just remove `;` after `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Line 3:**

Wrap the `forEach` callback body in brackets

```
let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => {
  if (typeof el !== 'string') { 
    console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`);
  } 
})
```

**Line 4:**

Remove semi-colon

```
let checkArr = (arr) => { 
  arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null )
}
```

**Recommended:**

```
const checkArr = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (typeof el !== 'string') { 
      console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`);
    } 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you defined your function with an extra `(`

Solution for 3rd case:

```js
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];

let checkArr = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null
  )
}

checkArr(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues.

- Second functiopn definition should be written inside `{}`
- Thirst statement, remove unwanted semi column after null.

```js
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];
let checkArr1 = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => console.log(typeof el !== 'string'))
let checkArr2 = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => { if (typeof el !== 'string') { console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) } })
let checkArr3 = ((arr) => { arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null) })
checkArr1(arr);
checkArr2(arr);
checkArr3(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => console.log(typeof el !== 'string'))

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => {if (typeof el !== 'string') { console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`)}} )

let checkArr = ((arr) => { arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null )})

checkArr(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing the arrow function, if you're not returning the result in the single line then you should better wrap it inside the curly brackets. You haven't wrapped it in the curly brackets in the second case.

And for the third case you've an useless ';'.

I've fixed both the lines.

```
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => console.log(typeof el !== 'string'))

let checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => {if (typeof el !== 'string') { console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`)} })

let checkArr = ((arr) => { arr.forEach(el => typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null )})

checkArr(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

just missing some Braces so everythings fine i think...

```js
let arr = ['Custy Stomer', 'C. Oostomar', 'C.U.S. Tomer', 3432434, 'Custo Mer', 'Custopher Ustomer', 3432435, 'Kasti Yastimeur'];
console.log(arr);
var checkArr = (arr) => arr.forEach(el => console.log(typeof el !== 'string'));

var checkArr = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(el => {
        if (typeof el !== 'string') {
            console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`);
        }
    });
}

var checkArr = (arr) => {
    arr.forEach(el => {
        typeof el !== 'string' ? console.log(`Type error: ${el} should be a string!`) : null;
    })
}

checkArr(arr);
```